# Switch after Router seems to create own subnet

Tags: switch, router, subnet

I have a Router (Easybox 802) connected to the Internet. It has sockets for LAN-cables and a wifi-antenna.
One socket of the router is connected to a switch (netgear fs605 v2) in another level in the house, where some computers are connected to it. Others use the wifi provided by the router.

The thing I don't understand is, why the computers connected to the switch have a different subnet as the computers connected directly to the router via wifi. I'd like to have all computers on the same subnet.

All computers obtain their ip-adress automatically, the ones on the switch get a 192.168.0.-adress, the computers on the router get a 192.168.2.-adress. I thought, switches can only forward packages and will not create an own subnet, providing ip-adresses etc.

Is this a problem with the switch or the router? What can I do to have all computers in the same subnet?

---

Edit: Shame on me. Between the router and the switch was another router hidden in a wardrobe that set up its own subnet. Turning off the DHCP solved the problem, now the main-router is the only device assigning ip-adresses and every device is in the same subnet.

Thanks for all answers and comments! Maybe this whole question can be deleted as in the end the reason for the problem was a different than stated in the question.

Comment: Are your WiFi clients connected to a guest network, perhaps? Your switch isn't the culprit.

Comment: I guess the router seperates wifi and lan, what can be disabled within configuration.

Comment: Can you statically assign the wired and WiFi on the router to use the same subnet? If you can, your router should consider then both to be in the same network.

Comment: And if you can, get a workstation on the subnet as well, let's say the wired has ip 192.168.0.1, WiFi is 192.168.0.2 and the work station is 192.168.0.3. From the work station ping each one. If both pings are successful, then the wired and WiFi are in the same network.

Answer (score 1):

Your router might, by default, have two different subnets: one for wired clients and another for wireless clients.

This would be bit odd but I can see this as extra feature that the manufacturer implemented in the firmware.

Answer (score 0):

A normal consumer switch can't create a subnet or assign a different IP address to your clients, so I am almost certain this is something done by the router.

After having a look through the [Router Manual](https://www.business.vodafone.com/site/bus/public/enuk/support/50_business_solutions/50_office_solutions/vodafone_dsl_router/p_dsl_router.jsp) from Vodafone website, my best bet is that you have put the switch on a LAN port in the router, which is configured for DMZ.

I can't find anything in the manual, that mentions the possibility to set up multiple subnets.